# CSS3 shape not postioning correctly

Tags: css

I am trying to create a custom shape in CSS3 but I am having problems with the position of the object at certain screen resolutions.

What I am trying to make:

[image]

CSS:

```
.foobar {
    position: relative;
    width: 100px;
    background-color: #666733;
    color: #ffffff;
    border: none;
    padding: 5px 0;
    margin-left: 10px;
    margin-bottom: 5px;

}

.foobar:before {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    width: 110px;
    height: 22px;
    background: #666733;
    padding-left: 0;
    margin-left: -32px;
    -moz-border-radius: 100px / 50px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 100px / 50px;
    border-radius: 100px / 50px;
    z-index: -100;

}
```

The issue I am having is with the `foobar:before` at different screen resolutions looks off:

**iPhone:**

[image]

**iPad:**

[image]

**Desktop:**

[image]

How can I properly code the shape with CSS so that it will work with all screen sizes?  I have attempted to create `@media` with an adjustment of `margin-left` but I was curious to know if there is a better way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use `position: absolute;`, it's better to use `top, left, right and bottom` position properties. You will have consistency that way irrespective of the device. Look at the [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/zgXGQ/1/) and try for yourself.

**HTML**

```
<div class="foobar"></div>
```

**CSS**

```
.foobar {
   position: relative;
   width: 150px;
   height: 50px;
   background: #666733;
}

.foobar:before {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    top: 13px;
    left: -15px;
    width: 180px;
    height: 24px;
    background: #666733; 
    border-radius: 15px;
}
```